# How to read 3 lines at time in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new in shell-scripting. I want to read 3 lines at a time from a log file. I know how to do it line by line. I tried reading using `<` three times and calling the script itself from the script, but it did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
$ while read l1
> do
>    read l2
>    read l3
>    echo line1 is $l1
> done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

TCL script to reading 3 lines at a time from a file

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set prev_count -1
set fp [open "input-file.txt" "r"]
set num_lines [split [read $fp] \n]
for {set i 2} {$i < [llength $num_lines]} { incr i 3} {
  set line_3 [lrange $num_lines [incr prev_count] $i]
  set prev_count $i
  puts "$line_3\n\n"
}
```

- Open a file to read
- Split the file using split command
- use lrange to select the number of lines from a list